# Return 1 result on multiple line join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an orders and order lines table and I want to be able to select a few of the records from the order table into a temp table. This is easy, the hard part is that I want to also select into the temp table when a specific product was used in that "order". This the query I wrote, but I can't use it as it returns multiple results for each order depending on how many order lines exist.
Can any one help? I only want to see whether an order included a specific or a number of specific produts:

```
DECLARE @Begin_Date    DATETIME;     SET @Begin_Date    = '2015-04-01'
DECLARE @End_Date      DATETIME;     SET @End_Date      = '2015-06-30'
SELECT o.Location_Code,
       o.Order_Number,
       o.Order_Date,
       o.OrderIdealFoodCost
       o.OrderFinalPrice,
     CASE WHEN ol.ProductCode IN ('172352','172353','172355','172357','172360','172422','172429','172343','172344','172346','172348','172351','172427','172428') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Promo
INTO #OrderCostPrice
FROM Order_Lines ol (NOLOCK)
Inner Join Orders o (NOLOCK) on ol.Location_Code = o.Location_Code
and ol.Order_Date = o.Order_Date 
and ol.Order_Number = o.Order_Number
WHERE o.Order_Date BETWEEN @Begin_Date AND @End_Date
and o.Order_Status_Code <= 98
and ol.Deleted = 0
```

Orders Table:

```
Location_Code|Order_Number|Order_Date|OrderIdealFoodCost|OrderFinalPrice|Order_Status_Code
30542        |1           |2015-01-01| 5.21             | 21.25         |4
30548        |1           |2015-01-01| 8.25             | 58.26         |4
```

Order Lines Table:

```
Location_Code|Order_Number|Order_Date|Order_Line_Number|Order_Product|Deleted
30542        |1           |2015-01-01|1                |172352       |0
30542        |1           |2015-01-01|2                |72352        |0
30542        |1           |2015-01-01|3                |72355        |0
30542        |1           |2015-01-01|4                |72358        |0
30548        |1           |2015-01-01|1                |72352        |0
30548        |1           |2015-01-01|2                |72358        |0
30548        |1           |2015-01-01|3                |72359        |0
```

Desired Result:

```
Location_Code|Order_Date|Order_Number|OrderIdealFoodCost|OrderFinalPrice|Promo
30542        |2015-01-01|1           |5.21              |21.25          |1
30542        |2015-01-01|1           |8.25              |58.26          |0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting all results from the order and flagging if something exists you could include the check in the select statement like below:

```
DECLARE @Begin_Date    DATETIME;     SET @Begin_Date    = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @End_Date      DATETIME;     SET @End_Date      = '2015-01-30'


--INSERT INTO #OrderCostPrice
SELECT o.Location_Code,
    o.Order_Number,
    o.Order_Date,
    o.OrderIdealFoodCost,
    o.OrderFinalPrice,
Promo = CASE WHEN (
                 SELECT count(*) FROM Order_Lines WHERE Location_Code =  o.Location_Code 
                    AND Order_Date = o.Order_Date 
                    AND Order_Number = o.Order_Number
                    AND Order_Product  IN ('172352','172353','172355','172357','172360','172422','172429','172343','172344','172346','172348','172351','172427','172428')
                 ) > 0 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM Orders o (NOLOCK)
WHERE o.Order_Date BETWEEN @Begin_Date AND @End_Date
AND o.Order_Status_Code <= 98
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I want my result set to include all orders with a bit value marking the products existence in the order or not, I adjusted my description to explain it a little better.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your change to the question. I think I have a better understanding of what your goal is.

Comment: I thought of that at one point, I didn't think it would work because it relies another independent select statement .. I will give it a go though

Comment: I was missing an END on the CASE statement. Could you post an example of what you used?

Comment: I took another copy of what you have there, and ran that, it doesn't work ... (I had to add a , after FoodCost .. but it's still a seperate select statement .. I've tried that method with out success.

Comment: I went through the steps of creating the data structure in your question, and built the query to get the exact results in your question. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use `exists` in the `where` clause rather than a `join`.  Your columns seem to all be from the `orders` table:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o (NOLOCK)
WHERE o.Order_Date BETWEEN @Begin_Date AND @End_Date and
      o.Order_Status_Code <= 98 and
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Order_Lines ol
              WHERE ol.Location_Code = o.Location_Code and
                    ol.Order_Date = o.Order_Date and
                    ol.Order_Number = o.Order_Number and
                    ol.Deleted = 0 and
                    ol.ProductCode IN ('172352', '172353', '172355', '172357', '172360', '172422', '172429', '172343', '172344','172346', '172348', '172351', '172427', '172428') 
             )
```

EDIT:

If you want a flag, then just move the logic to the `select`1:

```
SELECT o.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM Order_Lines ol
                          WHERE ol.Location_Code = o.Location_Code and
                                ol.Order_Date = o.Order_Date and
                                ol.Order_Number = o.Order_Number and
                                ol.Deleted = 0 and
                                ol.ProductCode IN ('172352', '172353', '172355', '172357', '172360', '172422', '172429', '172343', '172344','172346', '172348', '172351', '172427', '172428') 
                         )
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Flag
FROM Orders o (NOLOCK)
WHERE o.Order_Date BETWEEN @Begin_Date AND @End_Date and
      o.Order_Status_Code <= 98;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want my result set to include all orders with a bit value marking the products existence in the order or not, I adjusted my description to explain it a little better.